# C++2017 Reference to std::vector<std::variant>

Tags: c++, c++17, stdvector, std-variant

I try to store a reference to a `std::vector` consisting of `std::variant`.
I can create a `const std::variant<T>&` to a element of a `vector`, but I struggle to store the reference to the whole vector. I guess that the answer is related to this post [c++ variant class member stored by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41139135/c-variant-class-member-stored-by-reference) but I am not able to apply it to my situation.

```
#include <vector>
#include <variant>

using MType = std::variant<int, double>;
int main()
{
      std::vector<int> intVec{ 1,2,3,4 };
      std::vector<double> dlVec{ 1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4 };

      const MType& refVar = intVec[0];
      // const std::vector<MType>& refVec = intVec; // compiler error: not suitable construction 
}
```

Comment: Having a reference to something implies having that thing. You don't have any `std::vector<MType>` in your code, therefore you cannot have any `std::vector<MType>&`.

Answer (score 4):

You can assign an `int` to a `variant<int, double>`, and you can assign a `double` to a `variant<int, double>`, but neither *is* a `variant<int, double>` and a `vector<variant<int, double>>` is not a `vector<int>` or a `vector<double>`.

You simply can't do this.

Is it possible that you meant `variant<vector<int>, vector<double>>`?

Comment: Thank you, I can use variant<vector<int>, vector<double>> instead

Comment: @StephanH Okay. Before we go I would caution that this seems potentially unusual and you should double-check that your design is as it should be. Not that I've _never_ put vectors in variants though!

Answer (score 0):

> I can create a `const std::variant&` to a element of a vector,

With

```
const MType& refVar = intVec[0];
```

you don't create reference to element of `intVec` but create a temporary (with life time extension).

So it is basically:

```
const std::variant<int, double> var = intVec[0];
```

> but i struggle to store the reference to the whole vector

In the same way with `std::vector`, you might create a `std::vector<std::variant<int, double>>`:

```
std::vector<std::variant<int, double>> varVec(intVec.begin(), intVec.end());
```